# If $\mu$ has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, is $C_c(\mathbb R)$ dense in $L^p(\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

> Is $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ dense in $L^p(\mu)$ for all $p\ge1$?

Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. We know that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\lambda)$ for all $p\ge1$. Since, $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb R)$, we can conclude that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\lambda)$ for all $p\ge1$.

Now, I'm especially interested in the case where $\mu$ has a density $f$ with respect to $\lambda$. It would be even fine for me to assume that $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$ and that $f>0$. Moreover, it would be sufficient for me to obtain the desired claim for $p=2$?

Is there any chance to use the known result for the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Can we assume $\mu$ is a finite measure (i.e., that $\int f <\infty$)?

Comment: Stone Weierstrass ?

Comment: The result will be true if $\mu$ is sigma finite by convolution.

Comment: @DavidBowman As I wrote in the question, $\mu$ is a probability measure. So, clearly $\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda=1$.

Comment: @WillM. $\mu$ is a probability measure. Could you provide details?

Comment: I missed that then. So then you can show that $\mu$ is a Borel-regular measure, and from there the usual proof holds.

Comment: @0xbadf00d after checking my notes, I misremembered the result. I know that, on any Lie group with Haar measure, the infinitely many times differentiable functions with compact support are dense on any $\mathscr{L}^p.$ I am not sure about what happens in this one, and not only that, I tried it for a bit and I can't quite pass some limits. The main difficulty is that when you approximate $g$ with $g_n$ for Lebuesgue measure, the bads bits of $f$ kill the good ones of $|g_n - g|^p$ more than the tiny measure where this happens.

Comment: @DavidBowman Do you have a reference?

Comment: @DavidBowman I guess it should follow from [Theorem 29.14 in the book of Bauer](https://books.google.com/books?id=kgltaIW_fHwC&pg=PA186&lpg=PA186&dq=bauer%20%2229.14%20theorem%22&source=bl&ots=06wdNzstFF&sig=ACfU3U1kusXPYT1AO90mXNR_99AtSHwqmQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjyj7Tc-vzfAhXMaFAKHYNEDogQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=bauer%20%2229.14%20theorem%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following general statement which you can find in *Measures, Integals and Martingales* by R. Schilling (Corollary 17.9 in the 2nd edition).

> **Theorem:** Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ which assigns finite measure to compact sets. Then the compactly supported smooth functions $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are dense in $L^p(\mu)$ for any $p \geq 1$.

If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, then the assumption that $\mu$ assigns finite measure to compact sets is trivially satisfied, and hence $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$ for all $p \geq 1$.